# Jest: testing inner function is called

Tags: jestjs

Given the below, how do I make sure that the inner `foo` function is called with the correct message when the `bar` function is executed? Thanks.

```
const foo = (message) => console.log(message);

const bar = () => foo('this is a message');

test('test that the foo function is called with the correct message when the bar' +
     ' function is executed', () => {
  bar();
  expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('this is a message');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock `foo` function like this:

```
let foo = message => console.log(message)

const bar = () => foo('this is a message')

test('test that the foo function is called with the correct message when the bar function is executed', () => {
    foo = jest.fn()
    bar()
    expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('this is a message')
})
```

Comment: Thanks @kaxi1993! I realize now that this answer doesn't directly answer my issue, as I abstracted my issue too much. I posted a more direct question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814958/jest-mocking-conditional-function-calls) if you're curious.

Comment: You also point out that `foo` needs to be declared with `let` and not `const` - this solved a problem I was having.  Declaring both `foo` and `bar` with `function` also worked for me.