# Jest: mocking conditional function calls

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jestjs

I am trying to write a test to make sure that, when appropriate, a particular function (in this case, a sentry function) is called with a particular message. However, when I write this test, it fails, and I get the following message. How to I properly mock the `captureMessage` function in `handleError.test.js` to make sure that it is properly called with the `"this is an error message."` string in `handleError.js`? Thanks!

**error message:**

> Error: expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()
>
> jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy. Received:   function:
>   [Function captureMessage]

**handleError.js:**

```
import {captureMessage} from '@sentry/browser';

const handleError = (error) => {
  if (error.name === "ApiError") {
    captureMessage('this is an error message.');
  }
};

export default handleError;
```

**handleError.test.js:**

```
import {captureMessage} from '@sentry/browser';
import handleError from '../handleError';

class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'ApiError';
  }
}

test('When an ApiError is returned with no action type, sentry is notified', () => {
  const sampleError = new ApiError();
  handleError(sampleError);
  expect(captureMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('this is an error message.');
});
```

Comment: `However, when I write this test, it fails, and I get the following message.`
I might have misunderstood but I think you forgot the add the message

Comment: Also, you could use a [`Sinon.spy`](https://github.com/maurocarrero/sinon-jest-cheatsheet#spies-) on a different function that's called inside the conditional, when error.name is defined in your class.

Comment: You could also use `jest.spy()` to spy on the `captureMessage` method and then test if it was called with the arguments. For now you have no spy on stub on the method to test its arguments

Comment: Thanks @TomM, sorry, forgot the error message, it's in there now!

Answer (score 5):

As @balzee mentioned, you have to actually spy on the method you want to make assertions about. That causes Jest to replace the method with a special spy function that keeps track of the parameters it is called with, how many times it was called, and so on.

You should also provide a mock implementation for that function, so that you don't actually call out to Sentry when running your unit tests.

Finally, when spying on a method, you first pass the object the method is on, and then the name of the method as a string. Jest then replaces that property on the object with a spy function, that will call the original function if no mock implementation is given.

Without referencing the object the function exists on, you would just be changing what a local function variable points to, from the original/real function to a jest spy function. That won't change the function that the code you are testing invokes, so the test will fail.

So the final test should be:

**handleError.test.js:**

```
import * as sentry from '@sentry/browser'; // CHANGED
import handleError from '../handleError';

class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'ApiError';
  }
}

// added this to remove any spies/mocks after the test
afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});

test('When an ApiError is returned with no action type, sentry is notified', () => {
  const sampleError = new ApiError();
  // added next line
  jest.spyOn(sentry, 'captureMessage').mockImplementation(() => {});
  handleError(sampleError);
  // note the use of `sentry.captureMessage`, which is now a jest spy fn
  expect(sentry.captureMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('this is an error message.');
});
```